# Blooming Problems 1

Tags: riddle, knowledge

The types of me equal the greatest answer to life

I have really red betrayal without the rose for your wife

My "pinata" garden variety is a common inheritor

But my name is tarnished because of negative characters

Name the flower

Comment: @duck If you think you have an answer, please post it as an answer, with proper spoiler formatting.

Comment: Ok, yes can do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you a

> dahlia?

The types of me equal the greatest answer to life

> There are 42 different types of dahlia

I have really red betrayal without the rose for your wife

> A red dahlia symbolizes betrayal

My "pinata" garden variety is a common inheritor

> The garden variety of the Dahlia has scientific name Dahlia pinnata, they are very common

But my name is tarnished because of negative characters

> This could be a reference to [a murder case whose victim was known as the Black Dahlia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Dahlia) or perhaps [the book and movie based on that story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Dahlia_(novel))?

Comment: Yep, amazing job!

Comment: I was thinking about that one...

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Columbine (as in the flower)?

The types of me equal the greatest answer to life

> There are many types of columbine flowers, but not 42, so I am not sure.

I have really red betrayal without the rose for your wife

> The flower can be red, but the name is associated with the Columbine shooting, which probably could count as a betrayal.

My "pinata" garden variety is a common inheritor

> The columbine flower is used for decorations

But my name is tarnished because of negative characters

> The "characters" are the people who were involved in the shooting.

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

Different flowers are said to have different meanings so:

> Quacking grass is to mean anger and agitation, red primroses are to mean neglected, five-leafed clovers mean bad luck

I'm not sure that those qualify for the other lines but these are to be negitive

Comment: Well, the other lines should help narrow down flowers.